# How to place two columns in a row properly in this situation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I'm using Bootstrap I have coded this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5">
            <div class="slider-slick-img container">
                <div class="slider-for">
                IMAGE GOES HERE
                </div>

                <div class="slider-nav mt-5">
                    <div class="item px-2">
                    THUBMNAIL GOES HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5">
            <div class="">
            CONTENT GOES HERE
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result of this code goes here:

[image]

As you can see it separates the columns of **images** and the column of **contents** (product title, product description & etc).

However they are both placed in one `row` class.

So how to properly place them together in one row as the expected result shows here?

> ***Expected Result:***

[image]

---

**UPDATE #1**

If I remove `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12` from `<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5">` of the images column & content column, and also add `col-6` instead of `col-12` to both column classes, this result will appears:

[image]

However, as you can see, the *content* looks thinner and still have differences with the Expected Result image.

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: try col-6 instead of col-12

Comment: @webber I tried that but still shows the same result as before. And `col-6` also collapses the reponsive-design on smaller devices.

Comment: col-lg-12 doesn't look right. try simplifying your classnames and start with only 1 viewport size. then work from there.

Comment: Looks like its working. Which device size are you testing it for. I think you are testing on lg or md devices. you have added 12 columns for these. It will stretch out to the next row. Try testing on xl device or you could try col-lg-8/col-md-8 and col-lg-4/col-md-4

Comment: Try submitting your code as a codepen or something, complete with CSS classes, and images, the way you've written it, to make it easier for the others to troubleshoot

Comment: What is the actual image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repeating the classes and simply complicated everything here, you have to define where you want break to full row it'll automatically break at that screen size, you needn't explicitly add another class, adding too many classes will confuse you and anyone who has to understand the code later. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<header>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="">
        <h1>
          Cat
        </h1>
        <p>
          The cat is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal. It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="slider-slick-img container">
        <div class="slider-for">
          <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-67586673/67586673.jpg?3918697" width="100%" />
      
        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav mt-5">
          <div class="item px-2">
            <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-67586673/67586673.jpg?3918697" width="100px" />
                 </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I just add the `col-sm-6`, the result would be just like the **UPDATE #1** image which is thinner despite the Expected Result image.

Comment: in that case remove everything else and use only `col-lg-6` or  `col-xl-6`

Comment: `col-lg-6` Would show the same result as **UPDATE #1** shows, and `col-xl-6` shows the first image of question which is actually two separated columns!

Comment: If you want bigger image try using combination of  `col-lg-4` for one column & `col-lg-8` for image column

Answer (score 1):

In both of your columns you have added the class `col-12` which means that by default those columns will take all the row UNTIL you reach the first breakpoint which in this case would be `col-sm`. In order to fix this you have to specify `col-6` instead of `col-12` and if you check it in a screen size smaller than sm you'll notice each column is taking up to 6 places in the grid layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="slider-slick-img container">
                    <div class="slider-for">
                    IMAGE GOES HERE
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="slider-nav mt-5">
                        <div class="item px-2">
                        THUBMNAIL GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-6">
                CONTENT GOES HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice one, I figured out, removing `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12` from `col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-6 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5`  of the images column will fix it. There must be something wrong with `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12`. How to handle this and adjust the necessary settings for `lg`, `md` and `sm` devices?

Comment: @loctoj Theres's nothing wrong with those you mentioned. You are simply saying that in the bootstrap Grid which consists of 12 columns you want the column to take up to those 12 columns which is 100% of the width of the page so the next column neccesarily needs to go to the next row.

Comment: @loctoj Just give the first colum `col-8` and the second one `col-4` for example. I feel like you might need to check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example

Comment: I also tested it but it will ruin the layout completely :(

Answer (score 0):

Putting the div with content first and the one with the image after appears to mirror this layout correctly.

To define columns of equal width nothing more is needed than using class `.col` on each of them, as per [official documentation (Bootstrap 5.0)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example)

[image: expected]

---

[image: actual]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="">
                CONTENT GOES HERE
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="">
                IMAGE GOES HERE
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="">
                    THUBMNAIL GOES HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I just add the `col`, the result would be just like the **UPDATE #1** image which is thinner despite the Expected Result image. –

Answer (score 0):

Remove `container` class applied with `slider-slick-img`. It is not needed. And kindly share the link to your code where we can check with actual content(images and add to cart box). Else, with these texts, it is working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

> You should not set `12` on `lg screen` for both div,
> set `8,4` on `xl,lg`
> set `6,6` on `md`
> and set `12,12` on `sm`.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5">
            <div class="slider-slick-img container">
                <div class="slider-for">
                IMAGE GOES HERE
                </div>

                <div class="slider-nav mt-5">
                    <div class="item px-2">
                    THUBMNAIL GOES HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-xl-0 mb-lg-5 mb-md-5 mb-sm-5 mb-5">
            <div class="">
            CONTENT GOES HERE
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved your issue by opting for full responsive col's using grid system as shown in my code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="">
                CONTENT GOES HERE
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="">
                IMAGE GOES HERE
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="px-2">
                    THUBMNAIL GOES HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the meta tag "viewport" for your html code to be processed correctly by the browser.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", shrink-to-fit=no">
```

You can try putting this in the  section of your work.